# How to get index from fold expression

Tags: c++

I'm making a simple constexpr string encoder, see below.

```
template<char...Chars>
struct encoder
{
    constexpr static char encode(char c)
    {
        return c ^ size;
    }
    constexpr static size_t     size = sizeof...(Chars);
    constexpr static const char value[size + 1] = {encode(Chars)...,0};
};

template<typename T,T...Chars>
constexpr auto operator""_encode()
{
    return encoder<Chars...>::value;
}
```

useage:

"aab"_encode

"123"_encode

i want to get char index from encode function,like this

```
    constexpr static char encode(char c,uint32_t index)
    {
        return c ^ (size + index);
    }
```

or like this

```
template<uint32_t index>
    constexpr static char encode(char c)
    {
        return c ^ (size + index);
    }
```

But I don't know how. Any one show me how to do that?

Comment: You can't really "get an index" from a fold expression. This can likely be done by bringing `std::integer_sequence` into the picture and then do a complicated juggling act. Messy.

Comment: You can add a static index and increase it in `encoder()`

Comment: Please state your C++ version.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the whole thing in a single `constexpr` function in C++17:

```
template<typename T, T...Chars>
constexpr auto operator""_encode()
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Chars);
    std::array<char, size+1> ret = {}; // Maybe T instead of char?
    int i = 0;
    ((ret[i] = Chars ^ (size + i), i++), ...);
    ret[size] = 0;
    return ret;
}
```

(I made it return a `std::array` instead of a builtin array for everyone's sanity.)

Here's a godbolt link, including one of your test inputs (it helps if you include the desired output, nobody likes poring over ASCII tables and `xor`ing stuff by hand, even if I did that here):

https://godbolt.org/z/P8ABHM

Also, please don't use this to encrypt anything.

Comment: Unrelated to the original question: can you elaborate on the `operator""_encode()` syntax? Haven't seen that before. Does it have a name I can look up?

Comment: @supernun This is a literal operator (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). The above code allows one to write `auto x = "abc"_encode;`, which will invoke `operator""_encode` on the string `"abc"`.